# What does T+non-Cons(T) mean?

Tags: lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy

I am puzzled by the following question, which is about the philosophical meaning of some axiomatic system.

Suppose that a formal axiomatic system (containing arithmetics) $T$ is consistent. Let a statement $S$, expressible within $T$, be indecidable. Then (correct me if I am wrong) both theories $T$+($S$ is true), and $T$+(non-$S$ is true) are consistent.

According to Gödel, the consistency of $T$ is expressible but indecidable within $T$. Thus it seems that the theory $T$+(non-Cons($T$)) is consistent.

> What should I understand ? The above argument let me think that if $T$ is consistent, then it is not... Something must be wrong in the few lines above, but I can't see where.

Comment: Perhaps it is best to think of $T=$Peano arithmetic. Any model of $S=T+\lnot\mathrm{Con}(T)$ contains nonstandard numbers. For any actual number $n$, $S$   proves that $n$ is not the code of a proof of a contradiction (from the axioms of $T$). However, any model of $S$ contains "fake numbers", objects that do not correspond to actual natural numbers. But $S$ thinks they do. In particular, one such $n$ "codes" a proof of a contradiction...

Comment: ... but if you try to decode it you will see that this is really gibberish: it may be an infinite proof (there is no such thing), although $S$ thinks it is finite. It may  use infinitely many "axioms", some of which are not real axioms, but more gibberish, or finitely many axioms, but some of them are fake. So, this theory has a peculiar interpretation of what it means to be an axiom of $T$, which is probably wrong, and of what it means to be a proof from the axioms of $T$, which is also probably wrong. It sees a contradiction, but from the outside you can tell that this is not really the case

Comment: A further remark: one may object that the consistency of, say, $PA$ is expressible in $PA$, because the predicate "being a theorem of $PA$" is not representable in $PA$ (under a recursive godelization) by Gödel's first incompleteness.

Comment: I posted an [equivalent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2287867/415941) on MSE some years ago. There have been some enlightening answeres.

Comment: There is indeed an entire book devoted to clearing up ways people get confused about this topic: Torkel Franzén, *Gödel's Theorem: An Incomplete Guide to its Use and Abuse*.

Comment: I highly recommend this article by Raymond Smullyan "Logicians who reason about themselves" https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780934613040500284

Comment: Link to the Smullyan article that isn't paywalled: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.101.8548

Comment: Would the following be a valid way to restate this issue? The sentence "$S$ is expressible in $T$" isn't accurate, because $T$ gives no semantics, only syntax.  Instead, we should say "the metatheoretical statement $S$ can be encoded as a statement $\phi$ which is soundly interpreted in at least one model of $T$".  However, it could be (and often is) the case that this sound interpretation occurs only in models satisfying $\phi$ (but never the negation of $\phi$).

Answer (score 25):

For mathematicians of an algebraic bent it may be helpful to think of a nonstandard model of, say, Peano arithmetic as a very funny sort of ring (really a semiring), obtained by starting from $\mathbb{N}$ and adjoining some nonstandard numbers, in the same way we construct $\mathbb{C}$ by starting from $\mathbb{R}$ and adjoining a square root of $-1$. A model of $PA + \text{Con}(\neg PA)$ is like "$\mathbb{N}$ adjoin the [Godel code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering) $p$ of a proof of a contradiction in PA."

It's worth saying "Godel code" because $p$ is *not* a proof that PA is inconsistent. What it is is something stranger: we use the fact that PA can talk about, say, Turing machines to write down a complicated first-order formula $\phi$ which, *when applied to standard natural numbers*, tells us which standard natural numbers are the Godel codes of a proof of a contradiction in PA. Then we adjoin a "formal solution" $p$ satisfying $\phi$.

$\phi$ has only been constructed to have a particular interpretation when applied to standard natural numbers, and as it turns out the behavior of $\phi$ on nonstandard natural numbers is otherwise pretty unconstrained. There's an analogous but simpler discussion we can have about passing from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ by adjoining a square root of $-1$; you might imagine a 14th century mathematician being very confused about the fact that [the field axioms + the axiom that there exists an element $x$ such that $x^2 = -1$] is consistent, because they're used to a particular interpretation of what $x^2$ means (say that it measures the area of a square of side length $|x|$) that is only valid in $\mathbb{R}$, and the existence of a solution in a larger field involves a different interpretation from the one they're used to.

I am not sure what happens exactly if you attempt to decode $p$ as Andres describes in the comments. I think basically if you ask any question about the proof $p$ is supposed to be encoding which can be expressed as a first-order proposition, $p$ will just respond in whatever way it needs to to avoid a contradiction, but you won't learn anything useful. One possibility (and I haven't thought carefully through how much sense this makes) is that you can only ask questions about, say, the first $n$ lines of the proof, and $p$ will just tell you, for any particular $n$, that the first $n$ lines of the proof are totally fine, no problem here, but the proof may be "infinite" in the sense that $p$ may just sit around proving useless lemmas forever.

There's again an analogous but simpler discussion to have about the first-order properties of $i \in \mathbb{C}$: our 14th century mathematician may attempt to ask questions like "is $i$ contained in the interval $[a, b], a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$?" In $\mathbb{R}$ this question can be asked in the first-order language of fields, because in $\mathbb{R}$ we can encode $x \le y$ as $\exists z : y - x = z^2$. But this encoding only has its intended interpretation in $\mathbb{R}$: in $\mathbb{C}$ every number has a square root so "$x \le y$" is always true in $\mathbb{C}$, so our mathematician will learn that "$i$ is contained in every interval $[a, b]$," except not really, because again the construction we're using to talk about $\le$ only has its intended interpretation in $\mathbb{R}$.

The opposite sort of thing happens if we try to locate $p$: it will happily report that, for any positive integer $n$, it is greater than $n$. It does *not* follow, of course, that $\forall n : p \ge n$, because PA proves that no such number exists. This is already a little wacky if you're not used to it: if you add a constant symbol $p$ to PA and the axioms $p \ge 0, p \ge 1, p \ge 2, \dots$, this set of axioms is consistent (e.g. by the [compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem)) and so has a model, which we can take to be an [ultrapower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) of $\mathbb{N}$. It is maybe worth working carefully through why the statement $\neg \forall n : p \ge n$ continues to be true in this ultrapower: it's because we are now quantifying over all nonstandard natural numbers.

Comment: Re: the first paragraph, however, it's worth keeping in mind that building a nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$ is much harder than adjoining an element to a (semi)ring: e.g. by [Tennenbaum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem) no nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$ is computable. We can indeed build a nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$ as the free object *of a particular kind* on one generator, but the relevant kind of object is far more complicated than a semiring.

Comment: @Noah: right, there are many more "operations" involved. I think the analogy is helpful as a bridge to more familiar mathematical reasoning about "ordinary" mathematical objects where there's less confusion about what various things mean.

Answer (score 11):

While I don't disagree with the substance of what Qiaochu Yuan and Andrés Caicedo have said, I'm not happy with the terms "gibberish" or "useless."

It's important to bear in mind that when we say "consistency," we have a particular syntactic notion in mind, and that there is no canonical way of expressing it in terms of the semiring operations $+$ and $\times$.  It is easy to glibly write down "Con" and think that it *means* "consistent," but in fact "Con" is an enormously complicated formula.  We construct it by noting that syntactic operations on strings can be faithfully mimicked by arithmetic operations on natural numbers. Strings—sequences of symbols—can be faithfully encoded as natural numbers, and proofs—sequences of strings—can also be faithfully encoded as natural numbers.  Formally, "Con(PA)" is just an assertion that a certain $x$ satisfying certain properties does not exist.

When all the dust settles, we can examine this monstrous expression "Con(PA)" and confirm that if the quantifiers are interpreted as quantifying over the natural numbers and the symbols $+$ and $\times$ are interpreted as addition and multiplication, then the resulting statement will be true if and only if PA is consistent.  But it's very important to notice that "Con(PA)" does not directly "mean" that PA is consistent.  It's a formal string that is getting interpreted as a statement about the natural numbers, and the statement about the natural numbers is something that we can see, because of the way we carefully mimicked syntactic operations by arithmetic operations at every step of the construction, will be true if and only if PA is consistent.

If we now interpret "Con(PA)" in terms of the elements of some other semiring, then it is certainly true that the resulting statement will no longer have the property that it will be true if and only if PA is consistent.  But I think it is unfair, and more importantly misleading, to say that the statement is "gibberish."  "Con(PA)" has a perfectly meaningful interpretation in any semiring satisfying the axioms of PA.  What moral obligation does this other semiring have to mimic our intuitions about syntax? None, of course.  If we call certain types of semiring elements "proofs" and if that choice of terminology causes us to mistakenly assume that "proofs" will always have the same properties in other semirings that they do in the natural numbers, then that's our fault for choosing terminology that confuses ourselves.  Similarly, to use the word "useless" seems to presuppose that the only purpose in life a semiring might have is to satisfy our desire to understand syntax, but who are we to play God to semirings?

It's entirely conceivable to me that the theory of "generalized proofs" in "generalized natural numbers" will one day yield important mathematical insights. Admittedly they don't seem to have done so yet, but that's not a reason to dismiss it all as useless gibberish.

Comment: I think you are twisting the meaning. I clearly meant "this is not a proof", "this is not a formula", "this is not even a sequence of 'formulas' " and so on. Anyway, calling gibberish "gibberish" is not unfair to abstract concepts, that's ridiculous.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo : Yes, I understand your use of "gibberish" and my use of "unfair" is in the same vein. I'm suggesting that for the purposes of disentangling the stated confusion, it is psychologically helpful to place all models on an equal footing (to the extent possible), rather than unduly privilege one of them.

Comment: I believe that is more confusing (requires more logical sophistication, to the point that the question would be unnecessary).

Comment: Anyway, the models are not in equal footing, as one is an initial segment of the other. One can imagine a hierarchy of models where each is ill-founded with respect to another one. This would be more "fair", I suppose. Still, there is no equal footing as we can identify the ordering of the  models.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo yes and no. Yes, if we consider the category of models of PA, then N is the initial object (there is an initial segment which is a copy of N in each of them. No, from the INTERNAL point of view of each of them. Living in a PA model one thinks that it is N (in other words, no model thinks that is is made of standard and non standard numbers) , and, what is more important, the initial segment (the "true" arithmetic) is NOT M-definable. So in this respect Tim's point of view is extremely interesting (I may write my own answer along the same line, but even more radically)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo : Certainly the models are not on an equal footing in that sense. But they are equal in the sense that *none of them is explicitly a syntactical entity*. They're all *algebraic* entities. I really do believe that this is what confuses non-experts. They see "Con" and think that the formula itself expresses something syntactical. The first thing for them to grasp is that it expresses a perfectly meaningful algebraic fact in any model, and that getting it to line up with something syntactical in the standard model requires careful control.

Comment: @Mirco The point is that the claim that there is an N is a metamathematical commitment of some strength. Many of us make it implicitly, but justifying it is harder mathematically. You can imagine a setting where there is no such initial object (any N is illfounded from the point of view of a 'prior' setting). Anyway, look forward to your answer.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo holy words! Should be posted on some giant billboard.. Yes, N is a HUGE metamathematical commitment. Nothing wrong with that, of course. What is wrong is sweeping it under the rug. Anyway, shall post my answer, but do not hold your breath in the meantime: right now I am busy cooking my italian risotto, and that is a sacred operation, requiring all my  unflinching attention...

Comment: @Mirco :-) Enjoy!

Comment: The claim that the syntactic concept of "consistency" makes sense is also a metamathematical commitment of some strength.

Comment: Agree Tim, in fact I will tackle the bull by the horn exactly on that point: time to "contextualize" consistency!

Answer (score 1):

My answer is more of an extended comment on what Tim has already said. I guess what is at stake here is precisely this question: *what does it mean the expression $CON(PA)$?*

The common consensus is that it is a **metamathematical statement**, and indeed it is.

But what is metamathematics? Answer: other mathematics. In principle there is no distinction between Proof Theory of Peano Arithmetics, and , say, the Theory of Sobolev Spaces. In proof theory one studies structures, such as **proof trees**, which, in their intended meaning, talk about formal proofs of an underlying math theory, in this case Peano Arithmetics. But here is the deal: thanks to a **special encoding**, one can express certain statements of the "meta"-theory in the base theory, and so, in the case of PA, models of such a theory have some arithmetical statements which code some metamathematical facts on the theory. One of these is the infamous **CON(PA)**.

Now, let us imagine the **category of countable models of PA**, with corresponding maps. That is our "**Arithmetical Multiverse**". The chief point to unravel the seeming paradox raised by the PO is that PA does not know anything about actual infinity.

**All models, bar none, "think" that they are made of standard numbers**.

It so happens that, "from outside" (ie from the perspective of an underlying set theoretical universe), the category above has a distinguished object, namely an initial object. We call that **initial object** **$N$**. The metamathematics encoded in $N$ is the "true" metamathematics, and everything else is (again, that is common folklore), gibberish.

But let us take a slightly different look at the story:

let us assume for a moment that all models of PA are in some sense equal. Each has its own coded meta-theory. In some of them, NON-CON(PA) is true. If this statement happened to be true in $N$ it would be an earthquake, because in that case there would be a finite term witnessing a proof of inconsistency. But (assuming the consistency of PA), that is not the case. Note that, although N is an initial segment of all of the arithmetical universes, none has any idea about it, they have no capability to define it with a first-order formula. Everything looks to them just some standard arithmetics.

Now, let us play this game: to every model of PA let us assign a radius, the **Radius of Consistency**: it is measured by an element in the model, the minimal element (when it is there!) that proves the inconsistency of PA.

If that element does not exist, we say that the radius for that model is unbounded. Note *en passant*: as all models have the same order type, namely ω + (ω* + ω) ⋅ η, we can actually define the radius of consistency by its position in this order. I shall not pursue this topic further here, for the sake of brevity.

Armed with the Radius of Consistency, we can say that the conventional consistency of PA is the meta-statement that N 's radius is unbounded.

Similarly, there are models of PA who have a much  larger radius. Those are exactly the models which are conjured up by the PO.

You may say: all good and well, but these statements are still gibberish to me. Perhaps they encode garbage, useless information, as far as metamathematics goes (obviously, their are legitimate statements from the point of view of algebra).

Perhaps, but not so fast. For instance, sub-theories of PA such as $I\Sigma_1$ are finitely axiomatizable, so for those arithmetical multiverses the axioms involved in the "gibberish "are in fact real axioms. And things may get  even odder. I  think it is fair to say that so far nobody has done a detailed analysis of these statements of inconsistencies in complete details. There may be many surprises there. But here I stop...